# Find the value of a limit using a known limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, functions, infinity

I really have two questions:

Given that

$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\ln n}{n}$= 0,

how is it possible to find the value of:

$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\ln (n + k)}{n}$, where $k > 0$?

Similarly, given that

$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{n} $ = 1,

how could I go about finding the value of:

$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{n\cdot(\frac{5}{n})^n} $?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Your notation is wrong ($x$ vs. $n$). Your second case is quite easy, it seems that you didn't think of it for a second.

Comment: Hi @YvesDaoust, sorry if I seem like I haven't made an attempt. I'm utterly new to the entire topic, and I thought asking was appropriate when I got stuck, which I did. Thanks for pointing out the error, I've fixed it :)

Comment: Anyway, take a look at the second case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By a translation of the variable,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(n+k)}n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(n)}{n-k}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(n)}n\frac n{n-k}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(n)}n\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac n{n-k}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(n)}n.$$

---

Then,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n\left(\frac5n\right)^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n}\frac5n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac5n=0$$ provided the first limit is finite.

Comment: Thank you! The answer then comes out to be 0 due to the given assumption. Also, it turns out I mistyped the second case, would it be alright if you could take a look at it? Thanks again :)

Comment: @Chaptered "due to the given assumption": except that you didn't specify the first limit !

Comment: Oh my god, the post is full of typos... I hope there aren't any more...

Answer (score 1):

For the first:

$$\frac{\ln(n+k)}{n} = \frac{\ln(n+k)}{n+k}\cdot \frac{n+k}{n}$$

For the second, $$\sqrt[n]{n\cdot \left(\frac5n\right)^n} = \sqrt[n]{n}\cdot \frac5n.$$

Comment: Thank you so much, the answer for the first problem is then 0, correct? Also, I mistyped the second case--would you mind having another look? Thanks again :)

Comment: @Chaptered  For the first problem, yes, the answer is $0$. For the second, I edited my answer.

Comment: Removed, my answer since this is identical. +1